# Import Error while importing module from sibling directory

Tags: python, python-import, importerror

I was hacking over the weekend and happened across a strange issue. For some reason I Cant import modules from a sibling directory. I have no issues importing from a parent:

```
| src/
| ---- __init__.py
| ---- lib/
| -------- __init__.py
| -------- MyModule1.py
| -------- MyModule2.py # <--- I have no issues running `from src.lib.MyModule1 import MyModule1`
| ---- test/
| -------- __init__.py
| -------- MyTestModule1.py # <--- I cannot run `from src.lib.MyModule1 import MyModule1`
```

I have two modules in my lib directory, `MyModule` and `MyModule2`, and a test in my test dir. Modules in `lib` can use other modules as long as they have the same parent (`lib/`) but for some reason, modules in lib's sibling `test/` cannot use modules  in `lib/`.

When I try to run `MyTestModule.py`:

```
from src.lib.MyModule1 import MyModule1
```

I get this error: `ImportError: No module named 'src'`.

I do not get this error while running the same code in `lib/MyModule2.py`

What is going on here? Please help.

Comment: How do you run `MyTestModule.py`? What is the working directory?

Comment: eh, I'm using pytest from the project root. so one level above `src/`